# php - regex - how to parse the text within two different tags

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I have an HTML string like below:

```
$string = "\n<h2>heading 2</h2>\n\nwhatever we are doing is good to have one thing\n<h3>heading 3</h3>\nnext paragraph goes there\n<h2>new heading 2</h2>\n\npara succeeded for new heading 2\n\n<h2>heading 3</h2>\nand the rest of data";
```

I want the heading text (i.e. within <h2> and </h2> tags) and subsequent text (untill it finds another <h2>) or end of the string

I have tried something like:

```
$pattern = "/<h2>((?:(?!(<\/h2>)).)*)<\/h2>(.*?)(<h2>)?/is";
```

But this is not delivering the desired results.

I want to get as following:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => <h2>heading 2</h2>
        [1] => <h2>new heading 2</h2>
        [2] => <h2>heading 3</h2>
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => heading 2
        [1] => new heading 2
        [2] => heading 3
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => whatever we are doing is good to have one thing\n&lt;h3&gt; heading 3&lt;h3&gt;/h3&lt;h3&gt;\nnext paragraph goes there
        [1] => para succeeded for new heading 2
        [2] => and the rest of data
    )
)
```

Comment: Did you try `preg_match_all`?

Comment: the output I've pasted here is from `preg_match_all`

Comment: Your only output is tagged as *I want to get as following:*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this

```
preg_match_all('#<h2>(.*)</h2>([^<]*+)#isU', $string, $match);
echo '<pre>' . htmlspecialchars(print_r($match, 1)) . '</pre>';
```

Or maybe like this to you need

```
preg_match_all('#<h2>(.*)</h2>((?:(?!<h2>).)*+)#isU', $string, $match);
```

Optimized version

```
$pattern = '#<h2>(.*)</h2>(.*)(?=(?:<h2>|$))#isU';
```

Comment: it worked to some extent, I would say. But this is ignoring the `<h3>` tag and its text and from this patter I am guessing that it will not take any of the tags

Comment: absolutely fine... I reached upto `(?!<h2>)` but could go beyond your given solution...

Thanks buddy

Comment: one problem... its not working for heavy content... I am getting "_The connection was reset_" error... but if I reduce the lines of actual content... works fine... i think there is some problem with `*+` part in the regex but not pretty much sure about that... any work around?

Comment: You can specify how heavy the content? Because I just created a string with 336821 chars and tested my code, it works fine. Without errors.

Comment: its not working for even 287180 letters. any way to share my content with you?

Comment: @BhupinderSingh You can upload your file with data on any sharing site, and share link here.

Comment: Also if you're using UTF-8 encoding, you must add `u` modificator to your regex pattern.

Comment: @BhupinderSingh You're right, the problem was to use `*+` on large content. Now I optimized pattern. See my answer.

Comment: still no success... got three empty elements of array

Comment: @BhupinderSingh I don't know what is your problem, but try to use my code. Your file charset must be UTF-8 **Without BOM**
[here link](http://pastebin.com/4pYWYuTu)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25119/discussion-between-bhupinder-singh-and-winston)